# Создание файла Java

Tags: java, файлы

Здравствуйте, как создать файл на диске С? 
Когда делаю на D, все работает. Когда изменяю D на С ничего не происходит.

```
String path = "D:\\Program Files\\MyManager\\" + User_name + ".txt";

File file = new File(path);
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Comment: Скорее вы столкнулись с отсутствием прав на запись в директорию C:\Program Files со стороны Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее вы столкнулись с отсутствием прав на запись в директорию C:\Program Files со стороны Windows, но почему-то не видите ошибки в логах/выводе программы. Чтобы добавить доступ в директорию Program Files в Windows нужно в свойствах папки явно добавить своего пользователя с правами на запись (в зависимости от используемой вами версии Windows это может выглядеть немного по-разному, поэтому точного алгоритма дать не могу). ПКМ -> Свойства, а дальше смотрите.

Comment: Да, спасибо, ПКМ - Свойства - Снять галочку "Только для чтения"

Comment: Рад был вам помочь! =)